# Can I use a lithium charger for a bluetooth speaker with a NiMH battery?

Tags: power-supply, bluetooth, charger, lithium, nimh

I have a BlueAnt bt blast bluetooth speaker that I need a new charger for. It says DC 12V on the back by the power supply. I checked the manual and this speaker has a NiMH rechargeable battery. Can I use a 12v lithium charger for it? It seems really difficult to find any other kind. Also, the speaker has been sitting in storage for a couple of years and apparently you need to use NiMH batteries regularly for them to keep working. If it doesn't hold a charge, would it work if I left it plugged in?
Thanks!

Comment: Charger does not mean a power supply. Typically the charger is in the device, and you need a power supply. So you can't connect a lithium charger to it, if it just needs a power supply. The NiMH batteries may be damaged, so they might need to be replaced if they are damaged. Can't you find a manual to confirm this? I can't even find any product with that name, is the product name correct?

Comment: Here's the link to the manual: http://www.blueant.com.au/downloads/manuals/M1_manual.pdf So just to clarify, there is no difference in the power supply whether it is a lithium or a NiMH battery?

Answer (score 6):

No, you should not use a lithium charger, or any charger for that matter.

You should use what it says on the unit, a 12V DC power supply.

The charging circuitry for the battery is inside the speaker. It knows how to charge the battery, as long as there is 12V DC supplied.